# Iteration through an Iterable Async returns promise instead of result

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, asynchronous, async-await

I've been tearing my hair out on this one.  I have situation where I retrieve some values from an Azure App Configuration, then assign them to a single settings property inside of a singleton class.

What I'm getting back is a promise.  What I want back is an object with each property as a key-value, e.g.:

```
{
  TESTVAL1: 'Giggity Giggity ;-)',
  TESTVAL2: 'testing123',
  TESTVAL3: 'here we are again'
}
```

the idea is that when the class is intialized, the settings will be loaded from the Azure App Configuration, and will become available to any other part of the application that uses this code.

The problem lies with this function where I initialize the settings property:

```
class appConfig {
     private _settings:any // for now
        this._client = new AppConfigurationClient(process.env.AZURE_APPCONFIG_CONNECTION_STRING || '');
        private _instance: AppConfiguration;

     constructor() {
         this._settings = this.loadSettings();
         this._instance = this;
     }

    public getInstance() {
      this.log(['AppConfiguration Initialized...'])
        return this._instance !== null ? this._instance : new AppConfiguration()
    }

    private loadSettings = async() => {
      let loadedSettings:ConfigVars = {}

      const filteredSettings: AsyncIterableIterator<ConfigurationSetting<string>> = await this._client.listConfigurationSettings({
        labelFilter: process.env.AZURE_CONFIG_LABEL
      });
      for await (const setting of filteredSettings) {
          if (!setting.key.includes(featureFlagPrefix)) {
              const obj:any = {};
              obj[setting.key] = setting.value
              loadedSettings = {...loadedSettings, ...obj}
          }
      }
      return loadedSettings;
    }

   public get settings():ConfigVars {
        // returns a promise, should return an object
        return this._settings;
    }


    public getSetting =  (key: string) => {
      return (async () => {
          return await this._settings
        })().then(setting => {
          return setting[key]
        })
    }

}


const config = new AppConfiguration()
export default config.getInstance();
```

should be used like this:

```
import config from './AppConfig',

...
// val1 is undefined
const val1 = config.settings.TESTVAL1

// val2 is a <Promise>
const val2 = config.getSetting('TESTVAL1')
```

so - how can I get this to behave so that settings is just an object, not a promise?

Comment: You cannot convert async code to sync.

Comment: not true, not helpful.

Comment: If you believe asynchronous code can be converted to synchronous, then just do it. You don't need to ask a question.

Comment: config.getSetting for example always returns a promise.  It's never going to return the object you want.  Consider `config.getSetting('TESTVAL1').then(result => console.log(result))`

Comment: As long as your settings depends on an async call (`this._client.listConfigurationSettings`), it can't be defined synchronously. You'll have to either use the promise-wrapped value or somehow wait for a Promise to resolve before accessing any property of `settings`

Comment: Yes, I understand this.  That's what I'm trying to solve - do you have any suggestions?